# Doze behaviour on Nougat (7.0.)

Tags: battery-life, 7.0-nougat, doze-mode

Doze behaviour has been [changed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html) in Nougat. Doze is implemented in two stages

> When a device is on battery power, and the screen has been off for a certain time, the device enters Doze and applies the *first* subset of restrictions: It shuts off app network access, and defers jobs and syncs.
>
> If the device is stationary for a certain time after entering Doze, the system applies the *rest of the Doze restrictions* to PowerManager.WakeLock, AlarmManager alarms, GPS, and Wi-Fi scans.

My question: **What are the typical timings for step 1 and 2?**

- Even in Marshmallow , I could not find a reference to exact timing but was reportedly between 20 and 40 minutes.
- I am wondering if timings have been specified now, though my search didn't yield anything

Comment: This is interesting. Already tried asking at XDA? Maybe someone already explored the code.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman:  I didn't ask there  mainly because of high noise content but searched- couldn't come across anything. For that matter as mentioned in question, even Marshmallow timings don't have a definitive answer AFAIK

Comment: I guess that your best bet would be to ask Francisco Franco. He's the developer of Naptime, an app which forces Doze to be activated immediately upon the screen has been locked. Since the app allows the user to edit various parameters as to influence the deep sleep duration, time after Doze kicks in and so on, it means that the dev has the answer you're searching for.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman:Thanks. Been in  touch  ( not directly but reading up on XDA ) with app developers of Greenify, Force Doze, both of which implement this feature with similar parameters ( atleast in Force Doze) on Marshmallow. I currently use Force Doze. While you get a fair idea of commonality of 30 minutes on most devices, there are differences. The question is more like what did Google plan ? Didn't want to bring ask this spadework into the question for fear of losing focus. Thanks for your interest though. Incidentally both apps implement for both rooted and non rooted devices- //

Comment: You need to run adb commands for Unrooted Devices. That 30 minutes is for Marshmallow

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman : once these developers upgrade app to N, there may be an idea. Thanks again

Comment: I just looked up ways to contact developer. Reddit thread seems to be inactive, mailed him.. Let's see if he reverts... Thanks

Comment: Which dev did you write to?

Comment: Fransisco Franco from the app  mail

Comment: No problem, then. He seems to respond in a day or two.

Comment: I am not familiar with this function, but it should be manufacturer specific.